# Create a shipment for specific items in Magento via Soap API v2 for an order with configurable products - Cannot create an empty shipment error

Tags: php, magento, soap

I have an order in magento 1.x that has 2 lines. One of the line is a simple product and the other is a configurable product. Both product's `order_qty` is `2`.

I am trying to create a shipment for one of the configurable product for a quantity of 1.

Here's my `requestBody` (json object) defining the specific shipment I am trying to create:

```
{
    "orderIncrementId":"100006762",
    "items":[
        {
            "sku":"ABCD1234",
            "qty":1
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's part of my implementation showing the shipment creation:

```
// Parse shipment sku => qty hash map
$shipmentQtys = [];
foreach ($requestBody['items'] as $shipmentItem)
    $shipmentQtys[$shipmentItem['sku']] = (int)$shipmentItem['qty'];

// Load sales order info
$orderInfo = $this->getOrder($requestBody['orderIncrementId']);

// Build itemsQty from shipment
$itemsQty = [];
foreach ($orderInfo->items as $orderItem) {
    if ($orderItem->product_type != 'simple') {
        continue;
    }
    $itemSku = $orderItem->sku;
    $itemId = $orderItem->item_id;
    if (array_key_exists($itemSku, $shipmentQtys)) {
        $itemsQty[] = [
            'order_item_id' => $itemId,
            'qty' => $shipmentQtys[$itemSku]
        ];
    }
}

// Create shipment
$comments = '';
$email = false;
$includeComment = false;
$shipmentIncrementId = $this->apiClient->salesOrderShipmentCreate(
    $this->sessionId,
    $orderIncrementId,
    $itemsQty,
    $comments,
    $email,
    $includeComment);

// Debug
var_dump($shipmentIncrementId);
```

I am using v2 of the soap api, as outlined in the documentation here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrderShipment/sales_order_shipment.create.html

When my code runs, I get the following error:

> Cannot create an empty shipment.

So I dumped my `$itemQty` to make sure I had parsed the matching sku for a simple product and it had the correct data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_item_id] => 9657
            [qty] => 1
        )
)
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

//Try to check below line.

```
$shipmentIncrementId = $this->apiClient->salesOrderShipmentCreate(
    $this->sessionId,
    $orderIncrementId,
    $itemsQty,
    $comments,
    $email,
    $includeComment);

chnage to

$shipmentIncrementId = $this->apiClient->salesOrderShipmentCreate(
    $this->sessionId,
    $orderInfo->orderIncrementId,
    $itemsQty,
    $comments,
    $email,
    $includeComment);
```

Comment: I tried this and still not working. I think the problem is related to creating a shipment for a configurable product.

Comment: We can not do shipment for configurable product in magento instead of that do the shipment of config child product only.

Comment: I am aware of this. If you look at my code, when I iterate through the order items, I am only loading the `item_id` where `product_type` = `simple`.